# Mendix Retrieve last input value

Tags: mendix

In mendix i have 2 pages: Course Overview and Course_newEdit.

As the names suggest overview i the overview page and the second one is edit page.

The entity name is Course.
Its attributes are: Name String and Description String.

I have a requirement that i when a user edits course, the default value for name should be the last user input value.

So if the user has give first course name as History.
The second time any user tries to input the name, it should by default show History.

how can this be achieved?

I couldn't find any option for the same in the default settings.

Mendix 9.2 pro

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing an existing course than it will automatically show the value that was last stored in the database so you don't need to do anything there.

If you are creating new course and want the default value of 'Name' attribute to be automatically filled in using the previous course object, than you have to [retrieve](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/retrieve) last saved course object from database with [range option](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/retrieve#3-3-2-range) = 'First' and add [sort property](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/retrieve#3-3-4-sorting) that can identify the retrieve object as last saved course object. Than you can use retrieved last saved course and copy 'Name' to your new course object.
Please check out [Mendix Forum](https://forum.mendix.com) and [Mendix Slack Community](https://join.slack.com/t/mendixcommunity/shared_invite/zt-hwhwkcxu-%7E59ywyjqHlUHXmrw5heqpQ) if you have more questions.

**Mendix Forum:** https://forum.mendix.com

**Community Slack:** [https://join.slack.com/t/mendixcommunity/shared_invite/zt-hwhwkcxu-~59ywyjqHlUHXmrw5heqpQ](https://join.slack.com/t/mendixcommunity/shared_invite/zt-hwhwkcxu-%7E59ywyjqHlUHXmrw5heqpQ)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to retrieve the list  "Course" from database then sort the list by creating date descending then retrieve head of the new sorted list then fill this object in the new created one
course/name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).